# how to reduce size of git repository

Tags: git

I have a git repository with lots of `pdf` and `zip` files.
Can git treat them as just a file name? in this case, the repo should be very small.

I have tried to add a `.gitattributes` with the following lines:

```
*.zip   binary
*.pdf   binary
```

After I commit, the `.git` directory is still very large. Is there a way to reduce the size of my repository?

Any solution is welcome. such as recreate a new repository. The commit history is not important for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use the command

```
git archive <branch> > file.zip
```

And, ... I think that your repository do not care about zip and pdf: you really need to version documents? I think the best way is to version only code. Documents should be stored in another place, like data: data are often stored in a database and database is never part of the repository.

Comment: this pdf are papers i have read and i want to read. i have several PC. I cannot find a good way to keep them being synchronized. do you have idea for my requirement?